# Spring Application - Application Context IOC

Tags: spring

I am trying my hand on spring framework. This is my first basic spring application. I am following javatpoint tutorials. But I am getting an error. Can someone help me resolve it please.My code is as below

**Student.java**

```
package com.javatpoint;

public class Student {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void displayInfo(){
    System.out.println("Hello: "+name);
}
}
```

**Test.java**

```
package com.javatpoint;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    Student student=(Student)context.getBean("studentbean");
    student.displayInfo();
}
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="studentbean" class="com.javatpoint.Student">
<property name="name" value="Archana Ravindran"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**Error**

> Feb 10, 2016 9:56:39 AM
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3aa9f827:
>   startup date [Wed Feb 10 09:56:39 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.customizeBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:218)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at com.javatpoint.Test.main(Test.java:15) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 7 more

My **.classpath**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="melibrary.com.genuitec.eclipse.lib.spring3.MYECLIPSE_SPRING30_CORE"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Spring/spcorejars/org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Spring/spcorejars/org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Spring/spcorejars/org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

[image: Error that I am getting]
   [image: External Jar addition]

Comment: From the exception - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor

It seems like you dont have this class in your classpath. Could you please post pom.xml or .classpath file you are using?

Comment: I don't have a pom.xml file . And where will I be able to find .classpath files??

Comment: In your workspace.. Type CNTR+SHIFT+R. And the type .classpath. You should be able to find your classpath file.

Comment: from the error it looks like you are missing the jar file for 'org.springframework.asm' . Make sure you have the jar file included in your classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution to your Question**

1. While you are building for SpringFramework versions 3.X and above, it is recommended to use the **[Bill of Materials](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22spring-framework-bom%22%20AND%20v%3A%223.2.14.RELEASE%22)** and download all the JAR Files in your workspace classpath
2. In Your case you are missing asm.jar in your classpath, Hence you are getting this exception. Please download it from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm-all/2.2)
3. Also, permanent solution for your ClassNotFoundException, In your eclipse you have click CTRL+SHIFT+T, It will open the classfiles which is included in Jars. In your case you search for ClassVisitor as shown in the image.[image: open type]. If you are using **Java 7 and Java 8 version** no need to add this jar file. It is already built in as shown in above figure.
   [image: JDK 7]
4. If you are using Alternate JAVA versions, you have to download asm-all-5.0.4.jar from [maven central repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm-all/5.0.4) and place in your classpath.
5. Please refer the [image: figure given below] for placing in your classpath.
6. Please add [apache commons logging](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2) jar file in your classpath

Comment: I have included asm jar also. I am using JAVA 7 so your step 3 is already done. But still I am getting the error

Comment: @ Learner <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>  shows you are using Java 6 Version. Please download this jar file asm-all-5.0.4.jar and place it your classpath. Hope would resolve your issue.

Comment: I have downloaded it . But how to plcae in classpath. I included the jar from build path-> external jar but still the error persist

Comment: I have done that, still I am getting the error..I have updated my question with what I did

Comment: Thank you so much. It resolved the problem. An explanation on why to add these jars and when to add would be of much help. Because I have tried many basic java programs using the same IDE and same set up. But never got errors.

Comment: @Learning,  as your question needs deeper justification,  I have added as an another answer.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your comment question in short**

1. Springframework requires dependencies (jar files)to execute your program successfully.

**In an elaborate manner**

2. Usually basic java programs doesn't require any third party libraries as a dependencies. You need to import your jdk in IDE which will take care everything.
3. When you use to other frameworks like spring, struts, JSF you are exposed to the open source and outside world which requires multiple dependencies for these framework to run your java programs. Build tools like maven, gradle, m2e plugins(in your IDE)does a brilliant job in handling these dependencies.
4. If you want to find the dependencies you can execute commands offered by these build tools.
5. Every frameworks is designed/architected in such a way to address a specific solution. But remember one thing,  all these frameworks have been developed in 100% java. JDK Versions may take different dimensional advancements to make your life simpler in the form of functional programming.  But your  OOPS concept and Java Fundamentals will **never** change.